# Issue maintaining scope with jQuery / module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I'm just starting out using module patterns (thanks to Christian Heilmann's original tutorial) to organize my jQuery and I'm running into a weird issue. Consider the following javascript code:

```
var Gallery = function(){

  var $obj, $thumbs, $mainPic;

  function init($e){

    $obj = $e;
    $thumbs = $obj.find('.thumbnail');
    $mainPic = $obj.find('.main-pic');

    $obj.find($thumbs).bind('click',updateMainPic);

  };

  function updateMainPic() {
    $thumbs.removeClass('selected');
    $thumb = $thumbs.filter(this);
    $thumb.addClass('selected');
    newPicUrl = $thumb.data('src');    
    $mainPic.attr('src',newPicUrl);    
  };

  return {
    init:init
  }

}();
```

Which is included and used on the follow HTML:

```
<div id="gallery1">
  <img src="" class="main-pic">
  <ul>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo1.jpg">Photo 1</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo2.jpg">Photo 2</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo3.jpg">Photo 3</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo4.jpg">Photo 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Gallery.init($('#gallery1'));
</script>

<div id="gallery2">
  <img src="" class="main-pic">
  <ul>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo1.jpg">Photo 1</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo2.jpg">Photo 2</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo3.jpg">Photo 3</li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-src="photo4.jpg">Photo 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Gallery.init($('#gallery2'));
</script>
```

The problem I'm running into is that clicking the thumbnails on #gallery1 is swapping the image of #gallery2, yet #gallery2 is working as expected. It would seem the the $obj variable is being shared across the instances, but I thought it remained scoped to the private instance of the function.

Any advice on how to get this properly scoped and working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that Gallery is a singleton. The moment you call the second init, you're replacing the internal $obj variable.

I wouldn't use a module pattern in this situation. If you're using jQuery anyway, it'd be easier to write a jQuery plugin (simple) or a jQuery UI Widget (is really good at maintaining state).

Comment: @Bjork24 No problem - on a related note, check out this free e-book on javascript design patterns (http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/). Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your scenario for awhile, trying to see if a moduler pattern can be used; and it looks like a huge hurdle occurs during the binding.  It becomes very difficult to determine the scope for 'this' inside your updateMainPic() function.  Even with a powerful library like [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind), with their _.bind() function that allows biding to an object, cannot overcome this scenario easily.

Like Mike mentioned, a plugin or widget would make this particular task trivial:

```
$('li.thumbnail').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.main-pic').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The module pattern is more designed for singleton usage.  Each time you call your init method you are repointing your $obj variable to the passed $e. So simply drop the $obj move the other two into the init and pass the three parameters to updateMainPic.  If you need instance based pointers then have your singleton return a prototypal function that you can create instances of and bind directly to your dom click event.